# Is there a way to set expire date on Twitter access token?

Tags: twitter, set, access-token

I want the access token to expire before it is stolen by hackers.
Is there an API to provide? Or should it be implemented internally?

Comment: Which hackers are going to steal your access token? Is this a user token or an app token?

Comment: Due to the project structure, the access token is transmitted and used here and there. I want to set an expiration date in case the access token is stolen during this process.